# How to click and hold with delay with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, click, delay

```
def click_button_with_hold(self, btn, delay_in_ms=300):
    webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).click_and_hold(btn)
    sleep(delay_in_ms / 1000)
    webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).release().perform()


def button_find(self):
    send_sec_code_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#btnSendCode")
    self.click_button_with_hold(send_sec_code_btn)
```

I need to add delay when I click to some button, so I coded like that to click with 0.3 sec delay. But its not working for me. How can I handle that ? Thanks for answer

Comment: So you wanna add a duration in the click and hold?

Comment: Use pause(seconds) Pause all inputs for the specified duration in seconds https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.pause

Comment: Can you explain some with example please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import time

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.click_and_hold(btn).perform()
# sleep for 10 seconds
time.sleep(10)
action.release().perform()
```